# SQL server query stats for UDF

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

When i run a stored proc once and look at the query stats in sys.dm_exec_query_stats, i get the correct execution count, which is 1

but when i execute a UDF once, i see that it's execution count is 4 (there are 3 rows for that udf in sys.dm_exec_query_stats)

ObjName        ExecutionCount      AvgWorkerTime

---

fnGetDomesticNumber       1                3066
fnGetDomesticNumber       2                 411
fnGetDomesticNumber       1                 657

Can anyone help me understand this.

Thank you

Comment: What is in the UDF? query stats may pick up other (non result producing) queries (insert/update/delete/set/select) or other function calls or triggers.

Comment: It is a simple function , given an id, it returns a number.
And I execute it as follows 

SELECT dbo.fnGetDomesticNumber(10)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that SQL Server is recompiling the UDF.  You might be able to verify this by running the SQL Server Profiler and trapping the SP:Recompile event.

Also, depending on your SQL query that calls the function, SQL Server may invoke the function once per row of data.  That may explain the ExecutionCount of 2.